# Raspberry UART ports (GPIO14 & 15) show only "\xff"

Tags: serial, uart

I am trying to use UART port to receive a signal from Wiegand, but I am only receiving `\xff` when baud rate = 9600

```
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
```

When changing the baud rate to 57600, I start to receive:

```
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
b'\xe0'
```

baud rate = 38400, then:

```
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
b'\xf8'
```

I don't what's happening, but I was expecting to receive '100004' where all the previous values were wrong

Comment: We need a link to the datasheet of the Wiegand device you are using.

Comment: thank you @joan. here you are: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1558306/Faceid-F910.html?page=7#manual. I am using WGD0_OUT and WGD1_OUT

Comment: You need to edit links into your question.  The question should be all that people need to read to be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am looking this completely wrong, but on page 23 you have the pulse width. System Main Menu>2. Communication>2. Wiegand.
The default is supposed to be 100us. Now according to this: [Determing Unknown Baud Rade](https://www.kumari.net/index.php/random/37-determing-unknown-baud-rate)

You get this table:

> Time-->Baud Rate
>
> 3333µs-->300
>
> 833µs-->1200
>
> 416µs-->2400
>
> 208µs-->4800
>
> **104µs-->9600**
>
> 69µs-->14400
>
> 52µs-->19200
>
> 34µs-->28800
>
> 26µs-->38400
>
> 17.3µs-->57600
>
> 8µs-->115200
>
> 4.34µs-->230400

So yes, you should get something at 9600, but check what the value is in Pulse Width and maybe change it from 100 to 104 to match the above list for 9600 baud rate.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested it but it did not work. the device has "Width of Pulse" & "Pulse Interval". changing their value result in different output. I do not know how to find the correct values and to setup the baud rate correctly.

Comment: Hello mate, I had another look around and you will really need to have a look at this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100161/68240
Basically it says
Question
How to use Rpi UART to read Wiegand data?
Answer
No you can't. Wiegand and UART are different animals. They don't talk to each other.